# get Json object in Codeigniter with Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

> i want to get data that i called it from controller and display it when the drop down menu changed 
>   this is my model:

```
$query = $this->db->query('select ifnull(max(content_id),0)+1 as content_id from news_contents where news_id = '.$news_id);
    return $query->result();
```

> this is my controller:

```
 header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
 echo(json_encode($this->m_news_crud->new_newscontent_id($news_id)));
```

> and this is my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <form>
   <select id="first">
    <option value="201512001">Option 1</option>
    <option value="201512002">Option 2</option>
    <option value="201512003">Option 3</option>
    <option value="201512004">Option 4</option>
   </select>
   <div id="msg"></div>
</form>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var b_url = "http://194.1.1.236/abuqir-arabic-master/"
 $('#first').change(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var news_id = $('#first').val();
        console.log(news_id);    
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: (b_url + "c_news_crud/get_content_max/" + news_id),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });

        });

  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

> Data structure is :

```
[{"content_id":"4"}]
```

> it seems like it appear in browser developer tool put it doesn't appear in view
>
> and finally sorry for my languages

Comment: did you get alert(data); ??

Comment: the alert return [object Object]

Comment: Do alert (JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: after you will get data you just need to append data to html. Simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should append the `data` you get on `success` to the view, Try :

```
...
success: function(data) {
    $('#msg').text(data[0].content_id); //append 4 to the msg div
}
....
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it return [object Object]

Comment: You have to show us the object returned structure, and what you want to show in view.

Comment: now after editing i wrote (success: function(data) {
                        $('#msg').text(JSON.stringify(data));
                    }) and it return date like [{"content_id":"4"}] what i want is return number "4"